# Is there a way to create two login scopes within a single Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am creating a showcase site for this client and he also needs an admin page to manage the content for this showcase site. Well, ok, not hard, I'll just use Devise to create a login for the admin area and I don't need a login for the showcase site. But he also needs a intranet area for service orders and such, so I'll need two different logins, one for the admin and one for the intranet. Do I need to separate this in two projects or I can put the site, admin and intranet all in one project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a single app.  You just need to differentiate the type of user so you know what they can/can't access.  Maybe subclass your User model.  Or use a gem like declarative_authorization for fine grain control.